# How to read bytes via serial port sent by MCU in Python

Tags: python

From my MCU I send data like 0,1,2,3,4,5....254,255,1,2,3,4... to PC via serial port. I try to read it (in Python) and plot it. I save data to List, I would expect values in hex or decimal format, but in explorer I can not even see them  - what I am missing? You can see the var explorer with read values saved in y

```
def readFromMCU(i):
    y.pop(0)
    y.append((ser.read()))
    x.pop(0)
    x.append(x[-1]+1) # just increment x axis   
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: `ser.read()` is just going to give you whatever data has currently been collected in the serial input buffer; there is absolutely no reason for this to correspond to a single data value.  Most of the time, I would expect it to be empty, because no new data has arrived yet.

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly tell what your big picture is, but maybe this will help.  I have this running on my PC right now.  I am capturing files sent discretely rather than an ongoing data stream, but for the purposes of this I think the difference is negligible.

```
def collect_data(file_name):
    print(' ', file=sys.stdout);
    print('Writing ' + file_name, file=sys.stdout)
    ln = ser.readlines()

    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for s in ln:
            f.write(str(s.decode('utf8')))

    # ...and DING :)
    winsound.MessageBeep(-1)

with serial.Serial("COM1") as ser:
    ser.timeout = 0.5;

    print(ser.name + ' is open')

    wait_time = 1;

    # Main Loop monitors COM port and user key press, 
    # and displays a progress meter.
    while True:
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            collect_data(file_name)
```

I've snipped this out of a larger program so look at is as an example, not necessarily running code... :)